# Speed of light in vacuum in non-inertial frame

Tags: visible-light, reference-frames, speed-of-light, relativity

Does the speed of light remains $c$ also in non-inertial frames? Or it changes from frame to frame?

Answer (score 0):

Speed of light is constant in any frame.